# Spark BigQuery Connector vs Python BigQuery Library

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I`m currently working on recommender system using pyspark and ipython-notebook. I want to get recommendations from data stored in BigQuery. There are two options:Spark BQ connector and Python BQ library.

What are the pros and cons of these two tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python BQ library is a standard way to interact with BQ from Python, and so it will include the full API capabilities of BigQuery. The Spark BQ connector you mention is the [Hadoop Connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector) - a Java Hadoop library that will allow you to read/write from BigQuery using abstracted Hadoop classes. This will more closely resemble how you interact with native Hadoop inputs and outputs.

You can find example usage of the Hadoop Connector [here](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example).